# Atualizar uma Jtable que está numa JFrame a partir de um JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowsorter

O que estou fazendo é um pouco mais longo, por isso vou encurtar o problema com um exemplo mais objetivo:

Tenho um form de cadastro e criei uma Jdialog modal com os campos que eu quero pesquisar. Quando eu pesquiso na JDialog gostaria de filtrar as informações na tabela que está na JFrame. O problema é que não está funcionando.

Segue código (neste caso o exemplo é com o setvisible que tb não está funcionando, acredito que seja o mesmo problema):

VISAO (Tela de pesquisa):

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    FrmCadUsuarios frm = new FrmCadUsuarios();
    frm.tbVisivel(true);
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    FrmCadUsuarios frm = new FrmCadUsuarios();
    frm.tbVisivel(false);
}
```

VISAO (form de cadastro):

```
public class FrmCadUsuarios extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JTable tbUsuarios;
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

    public FrmCadUsuarios() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocation(550,250);
        criaTabela();
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tbUsuarios);

    }

    public void tbVisivel (boolean aa) {
        tbUsuarios.setVisible(aa);
    }

}
```

Chamo a `JDialog` assim:

```
private void tb_btn_pesquisarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  frmPesquisa pesq = new frmPesquisa(this,false);
  pesq.setVisible(true);
}
```

e tento atualizar uma `JLabel` na tela do `main` assim tem 2 botões, 1 deveria deixar a label visivel e a outra invisivel:

```
private void btn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  FrmCadUsuarios frm = new FrmCadUsuarios();
  frm.tbVisivel(this, true);
}

private void btn3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  FrmCadUsuarios frm = new FrmCadUsuarios();
  frm.tbVisivel(this, false); 
}
```

O Construtor do form pesquisa (`JDialog`) está da seguinte maneira:

```
public frmPesquisa(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
  super(parent, modal);
  initComponents();
  this.setLocation(1300,100);
}
```

Comment: Para fazer filtros em `JTable` você precisa usar a classe `TableRowSorter` passando seu `TableModel`. Adicione seu table model na pergunta para facilitar te responder.

Comment: Oi Diego! O problema é um pouco antes de chegar nisso. Não estou conseguindo implementar o Listener, por exemplo, se eu crio um JDialog com um textbox e um botao ok, queria atualizar o form principal com o conteudo deste, mas ele não vai. Já tentei de tudo. Vi exemplos de como funcionaria se fizesse o form só em código, mas estou usando a interface do NetBeans e não está saindo. Se puder ter um exemplo simples de como funcionaria seria ótimo. Obrigado :)

Comment: Ah sim, adicione na pergunta como você chama a jdialog no jframe, e como você retorna a pesquisa pra ele de volta. Com essas informações(além das que já tem) já dá pra te ajudar.

Comment: Sem problemas! Chamo a Dialog assim:                                           
private void tb_btn_pesquisarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        frmPesquisa pesq = new frmPesquisa(this,false);
        pesq.setVisible(true);

    }

Comment: e tento atualizar uma Label na tela do main assim tem 2 botões, 1 deveria deixar a label visivel e a outra invisivel:                                       
                                       
    private void btn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        FrmCadUsuarios frm = new FrmCadUsuarios();
        frm.tbVisivel(this, true);
    }

Comment: private void btn3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        FrmCadUsuarios frm = new FrmCadUsuarios();
        frm.tbVisivel(this, false);
    }

Comment: O Construtor do form pesquisa (JDialog) está da seguinte maneira:     public frmPesquisa(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        this.setLocation(1300,100);
    }

Answer (score 3):

> Como não foi informado se a pesquisa deve ser apenas uma
>   determinada coluna ou em todas da `JTable`, este exemplo pesquisa
>   em todas as linhas e em qualquer coluna.

A classe `RowSorter` é a responsável por tratar filtros e ordenações, mas para componentes como tabelas, há uma implementação dela chamada [`TableRowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html), feita para trabalhar com o `TableModel`, o que facilita bastante adicionar pesquisa em tabelas. Adicione na mesma classe onde você constrói sua `JTable` um atributo como o abaixo:

```
private TableRowSorter tableRowSorter;
```

Depois de construir sua tabela, atribua o model que passou pra ela ao `tableRowSorter`, para que ele filtre baseado no mesmo model da tabela:

```
 this.tableRowSorter = new TableRowSorter(seuModel);
```

Ou caso você esteja usando `DefaultTableModel` e métodos anônimos e não criou um model próprio(apesar de altamente recomendado que você [crie seu próprio TableModel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121513/28595)):

```
 this.tableRowSorter = new TableRowSorter(suaTable.getModel());
```

Uma vez atribuido ao `RowSorter` em cima de qual model ele irá trabalhar, agora atribua este `RowSorter` a sua tabela:

```
suajTable.setRowSorter(this.tableRowSorter);
```

Agora, recomendo que você mude a forma como chama o `JDialog`, o segundo parâmetro desta classe é um booleano que [informa se a janela é modal ou não](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog(java.awt.Dialog,%20boolean)), se você quer um modal, precisa passar `true`, dessa forma, o Frame fica bloqueado enquanto o modal estiver aberto:

```
frmPesquisa pesq = new frmPesquisa(this, true);
```

No seu modal(caso ainda não tenha feito isso), adicione um atributo do tipo `String` para armazenar o que for digitado para a pesquisa e crie um método que retorne esta variável. Este método que será retornado mais adiante para o Frame principal.

```
private String textSearch = "";//vazio pra evitar problemas com nullPointerException

...

   public String getTextSearch() {
    return this.textSearch;
}
```

No `listerner` do `JButton` do modal, você vai capturar o que foi digitado no `JTextField` e atribuir a variavel `textSearch` criada anteriormente, assim, ao fechar o modal, basta chamar o método `getTextSearch()` no Frame para receber a pesquisa a ser feita na tabela:

```
this.textSearch = this.seuTextField.getText();
this.dispose();// isso fecha o modal ao clicar no botao,
               // logo após capturar o texto digitado e retorna para o Frame
```

Agora, no seu `JFrame` principal, basta chamar o método criado no modal e passar para o `RowSorter` como um filtro:

```
String busca = modal.getTextSearch().trim();
tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + busca));
```

> A expressão `(?i)` é um `Pattern` da linguagem que indica que a pesquisa será  **[case insensitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)**, ou seja, buscará pelo filtro, independente de encontrar maiúsculo ou minúsculo. Pode ser removido caso você não deseje este comportamento.

O [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) remove espaços em branco em volta da string retornada na pesquisa, e o `setRowFilter` aplica o filtro em forma de `regex` e exibe as linhas que conterem em seu conteúdo a pesquisa digitada.

> Se o texto da pesquisa for encontrado mesmo que seja como forma parcial do conteúdo da linha(ex.: pesquisa 'eng', e na linha tem engasgado, ou engavetado), esta será retornada da mesma forma.

Veja um print de demonstração que fiz, para mostrar como funcionaria a pesquisa:

<kbd>[image: Tabela com todas as linhas]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

---

Nos links abaixo é possivel encontrar mais detalhes a respeito de filtros e ordenações em `JTable`, além de exemplos completos e funcionais.

[how to search an element in a JTable java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066387/how-to-search-an-element-in-a-jtable-java)

[JTable Row filtering by JTextField value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364436/jtable-row-filtering-by-jtextfield-value)

[How to Make Dialogs - Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

[Ordenando e Filtrando Tabelas com o Java SE 6.0(DevMedia)](http://www.devmedia.com.br/ordenando-e-filtrando-tabelas-com-o-java-se-6-0/1668)

[Implementando seu próprio TableModel(DevMedia)](http://www.devmedia.com.br/implementando-seu-proprio-tablemodel/31865)

[Table Sorting and Filtering](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=661371&seqNum=4)

[How to Use Tables - Sorting and Filtering(Oracle)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: @kirito a resposta lhe ajudou a resolver o problema? Seria interessante marca-la como escolhida, clicando no `v` ao lado, para que sirva de referencia para outros com problema semelhante.