# Como popular uma JTable com TableModel próprio?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Quando se está mexendo com [swing](/questions/tagged/swing), quase sempre esbarramos em ter que manusear tabelas e populá-las com algum tipo de informação. Para  situações mais simples, o `DefaultTableModel` resolve, mas quando se tem um objeto personalizado, a recomendação que recebemos dos mais experientes é de se criar o próprio `TabelModel`.

Como posso popular uma `JTable` com um `TableModel` próprio, usando esta classe de objeto, por exemplo?

```
public class Funcionario {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private int matricula;
    private boolean admitido;

    public Funcionario(String nome, int idade, int matricula) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.admitido = true;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public int getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(int matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public boolean isAdmitido() {
        return admitido;
    }

    public void setAdmitido(boolean admitido) {
        this.admitido = admitido;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Introdução

Para Criar um `Tablemodel`, é necessário estender da classe [**`AbstractTableModel`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html), que é uma classe abstrata com as principais funcionalidades necessárias para se trabalhar com o preenchimento da tabela. Podemos também implementar a interface [**`TableModel`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), mas a primeira opção já a implementa, adicionando outras funcionalidades que a torna mais completa para o caso.

---

## Principais métodos da classe AbstractTableModel

Antes de criar um `TableModel`, é importante entender o funcionamento de alguns dos métodos que iremos usar:

- `isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)` = recebe as coordenadas da célula(linha e coluna) e retorna um booleano que indicará se o conteúdo da célula é editável ou não;
- `getRowCount()` = retorna o total de linhas que a tabela possui;
- `getColumnCount()` = retorna o total de colunas que a tabela possui;
- `getColumnName(int column)` = recebe um índice e retorna o nome da coluna daquele indice informado;
- `getColumnClass(int columnIndex)` = recebe um índice de coluna e retorna o tipo de dado das células daquela coluna;
- `getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)` = este método é que preencherá a tabela, célula por célula, de acordo com suas coordenadas(linha e coluna).
- `setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)` = este método será chamado sempre que uma célula for alterada na tabela.
- `fireTableDataChanged()` = notificará todos os `listeners` que houve alteração na tabela e que a mesma deve ser redesenhada.

Com estes métodos, já podemos criar uma base de `TableModel` para que a tabela saiba como se preencher com objetos  do tipo `Funcionario`.

---

## Criando o TableModel

Iremos criar a classe `FuncionarioTableModel`, que receberá uma lista de objetos:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class FuncionarioTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    //aqui transformei em coluna cada propriedade de Funcionario
    //que eu quero que seja exibida na tabela  
    private String colunas[] = {"nome", "idade", "matricula", "admitido"};
    private ArrayList<Funcionario> funcionarios;
    private final int COLUNA_NOME = 0;
    private final int COLUNA_IDADE = 1;
    private final int COLUNA_MATRICULA = 2;
    private final int COLUNA_ADMITIDO = 3;

    public FuncionarioTableModel(ArrayList<Funcionario> funcionarios) {
        this.funcionarios = funcionarios;
    }

    //retorna se a célula é editável ou não
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }
    
    //retorna o total de itens(que virarão linhas) da nossa lista
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return funcionarios.size();
    }
    //retorna o total de colunas da tabela
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.length;
    }
    //retorna o nome da coluna de acordo com seu indice
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int indice) {
        return colunas[indice];
    }

    //determina o tipo de dado da coluna conforme seu indice
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case COLUNA_NOME:
                return String.class;
            case COLUNA_IDADE:
                return Integer.class;
            case COLUNA_MATRICULA:
                return Integer.class;
            case COLUNA_ADMITIDO:
                return Boolean.class;
            default:
                return String.class;
        }
    }

    //preenche cada célula da tabela
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Funcionario funcionario = this.funcionarios.get(rowIndex);

        switch (columnIndex) {
            case COLUNA_NOME:
                return funcionario.getNome();
            case COLUNA_IDADE:
                return funcionario.getIdade();
            case COLUNA_MATRICULA:
                return funcionario.getMatricula();
            case COLUNA_ADMITIDO:
                return funcionario.isAdmitido();
        }
        return null;
    }
    //altera o valor do objeto de acordo com a célula editada
    //e notifica a alteração da tabela, para que ela seja atualizada na tela
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        //o argumento recebido pelo método é do tipo Object
        //mas como nossa tabela é de funcionários, é seguro(e até recomendável) fazer o cast de suas propriedades
        Funcionario funcionario = this.funcionarios.get(rowIndex);
        //de acordo com a coluna, ele preenche a célula com o valor
        //respectivo do objeto de mesmo indice na lista
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case COLUNA_NOME:
                funcionario.setNome(String.valueOf(aValue));
                break;
            case COLUNA_IDADE:
                funcionario.setIdade((int) aValue);
                break;
            case COLUNA_MATRICULA:
                funcionario.setMatricula((int) aValue);
                break;
            case COLUNA_ADMITIDO:
                funcionario.setAdmitido((boolean) aValue);
        }
        //este método é que notifica a tabela que houve alteração de dados
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

O código está comentado sobre o que cada método está fazendo. Defini constantes como índice das colunas para o código ficar mais fácil de ser entendido, e as colunas já estão definidas em uma lista de `String`, mas pode-se adaptar como quiser, seja passando uma lista de colunas, como ocorre com o `DefaultTableModel`, ou definir diretamente no método `getColumnName`, mas acredito que isso seja complexidade desnecessária para este exemplo.

---

## Preenchendo a JTable com o TableModel

Uma vez pronto, há duas formas de se passar este TableModel pra tabela: passando direto para o construtor da JTable ao instanciá-la ou passando o model via método `setModel()`. Obviamente que, na criação da tabela, a primeira opção é a que deve ser usada:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class JTableExample extends JFrame {

    private JTable tabela;
    private JScrollPane scrollPainel;

    public JTableExample() {
        renderizarTela();
    }

    private void renderizarTela() {
        
        //4 ojetos criados para popular a tabela
        Funcionario f1 = new Funcionario("Roberto", 33, 1220);
        Funcionario f2 = new Funcionario("Diego", 25, 1615);
        Funcionario f3 = new Funcionario("Afonso", 25, 1458);
        Funcionario f4 = new Funcionario("Sergio", 42, 1165);

        ArrayList<Funcionario> funcionarios = new ArrayList<>();
        funcionarios.add(f1);
        funcionarios.add(f2);
        funcionarios.add(f3);
        funcionarios.add(f4);

        //cria um objeto do nosso model
        FuncionarioTableModel model = new FuncionarioTableModel(funcionarios);
        
        //instancia a tabela já com o model como argumento
        this.tabela = new JTable(model);
        this.scrollPainel = new JScrollPane(tabela);

        this.add(scrollPainel);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTableExample tb = new JTableExample();
                tb.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                tb.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

E o resultado:

[image: print da tabela em execução]

O mais interessante é que, por termos definido o tipo em cada coluna, não é necessário se preocupar com problemas de *cast* numéricos. Por exemplo, passar letras como idade ou matricula, a tabela já se restringe quanto a isso e não aceita um dado que não seja daquele tipo. É claro que se passar um número como nome, não vai ser impedido já que o mesmo será entendido como `String`.

---

## Conclusão

A classe `AbstractTableModel` possui outros métodos para deixar a tabela bem mais poderosa, e ainda pode-se adicionar outras funcionalidades como exclusão e adição de linhas, fazer operações com banco de dados, mas não será aprofundado por questões didáticas.

A partir do exposto, pode-se perceber que não é tão complicado implementar um `TableModel`, sem contar que ele facilita a manutenibilidade do código e torna nossa tabela bem mais flexível do que usando `DefaultTableModel`.

Claro que isto é aplicável a casos com menos complexidade, ou para fins acadêmicos, haja visto que existem componentes que facilitam e até automatizam esta criação(como os exemplos [**citados pelo Anthony Accioly**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121513/como-popular-uma-jtable-com-tablemodel-pr%C3%B3prio#comment253294_121514)), mas é importante entender seu funcionamento para saber manusear este componente.

Comment: Apenas para fins educativos, enquanto implementar um `TableModel` na unha é certamente um exercício interessante, na prática em 99% dos casos são atendidos por Frameworks genéricos como [JGoodies Binding](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/binding/), [Beans Binding](https://java.net/projects/beansbinding/) e [Glazed Lists](http://www.glazedlists.com/) com seus próprios modelos. No mundo JavaFX `TableView`, `TableColumn` e `ObservableList`  também substituiram a arquitetura baseada em modelos. Na prática é raro precisar implementar um `TableModel`.

Comment: Muito bom...
Otimo código e explicações.
Utilizei no Netbeans..Bingo...Perfeito
Fiz varios BEANS e DAOS.. Tranquilo..
Sucesso.....
Luciano Deluqui