# Como popular JTable?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

Tenho de preencher uma tabela com dados do banco.
Porém não aparece nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Minha Classe**

Inserindo informações na tabela:

```
 DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    String sql = "select * from eventos";

ResultSet rs = null;
try {
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(folha.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}


try {
while (rs.next()) {
    //pega os valores do bd para popular tabela
    dtm.addRow(new String[] {rs.getString("codEvento"), rs.getString("descricaoEvento"), rs.getString("referencia"), rs.getString("vencimento"), rs.getString("desconto") });
}
}catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(folha.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Leia essa também: [Como popular uma JTable com TableModel próprio?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121513/como-popular-uma-jtable-com-tablemodel-pr%C3%B3prio)

Comment: Se você ler a resposta aceita dessas duas perguntas, você estará mais que apto para fazer o que pretende.

Comment: Os dados vem do banco...

Comment: A primeira pergunta tem a resposta pra isso. A segunda eu ensino passo a passo como "modelar" a tabela conforme o "gosto",