# Adicionar linha com campos vazios num JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Tenho uma `AbstractTableModel` só que eu não sei como adicionar linhas em branco, quando apertar o botão add linha no meu frame eu quero que ele chame um método chamado addLinha() do meu ModeloTabela, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
    public class ModeloTabela2 extends AbstractTableModel {
    private ArrayList linhas = new ArrayList();
    private String[] colunas = {"DATA", "EVOLUÇÃO"};

    public boolean isCellEditable(int linha, int coluna) {
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList getLinhas(){
        return linhas;
    }
    public void setLinhas(ArrayList dados){
        linhas = dados;
    }
    public String[] getColunas(){
        return colunas;
    }
    public void setColunas(String[] nomes){
        colunas = nomes;
    }
    public int getColumnCount(){
        return colunas.length;
    }
    public int getRowCount(){
        return linhas.size();
    }
    public String getColumnName(int numCol){
        return colunas[numCol];
    }
    public Object getValueAt(int numLin, int numCol){
        Object[] linha = (Object[])getLinhas().get(numLin);
        return linha[numCol];
    }
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int coluna) {
        switch(coluna){
        case 0:
            return String.class;
        case 1:
            return String.class;
        default:
            return String.class;
        }

    }
    public void addLinha(){       //Aqui eu adicionaria a linha em branco...

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta adicionar um `Object` vazio no método `addLinha()`, e informar aos listeners que a lista foi modificada, usando [**`fireTableDataChanged()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged--):

```
public void addLinha(){ 
    this.linhas.add(new Object[]{});
    this.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

No seu `TableModel` o método [`setValueAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#setValueAt-java.lang.Object-int-int-) não está definido, e é justamente este método que diz ao seu model como adicionar novos objetos(linhas) em sua tabela. Veja na pergunta abaixo uma breve explicação sobre como criar um `TableModel` e usá-lo para popular uma tabela.

[Como popular uma JTable com TableModel próprio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121513/28595)

Comment: Eu ja tinha tentado assim, não da erro, mas também não faz nada, vi uns exemplos que faziam o addLinha() com alguma coisa dentro dos ()

Comment: @MatheusLopes você disse adicionar linha em branco. Pra adicionar uma linha numa JTable, obrigatoriamente você precisa adicionar um indice a sua lista com um objeto, seja vazio ou nulo. O Código acima foi testado e adiciona uma linha não preenchida corretamente. Se isso não é o que estava querendo fazer, tente editar a pergunta e ser mais claro no que precisa fazer.

Comment: Ue, é exatamente isso que eu quero... poderia me passar o seu código teste para eu verificar?

Comment: No meu botão do frame eu estou tentando chamar o addLinha() da seguinte maneira: ModeloTabela2 tab = new ModeloTabela2(); tab.addLinha(); sera que é isto que está errado?

Comment: Você setou o model na tabela?

Comment: Sim, tem alguma maneira de eu te mandar o código do meu frame? eu sou iniciante em jTables, to tendo bastante dificuldades com coisas simples...

Comment: @MatheusLopes veja a edição da resposta e siga o link que adicionei, lá, eu explico passo-a-passo como criar um tablemodel.

Comment: Nossa, agora eu fiquei boiando muito, não faço idéia de como faço o setValueAt adaptando para o meu código, parece tão simples, mas não sei como executar, preciso estudar mais sobre tablemodel, mas tem como me dar uma solução para o momento? obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @MatheusLopes você leu a resposta lá do link? Está muito bem explicadinho lá. E isso é outra duvida, se eu adicionar na resposta daqui, estarei fugindo do que foi perguntado. Dá uma lida com calma la na resposta, feche esta pergunta como aceita. Se mesmo depois de ler lá não conseguir implementar, faça outra pergunta sobre o setvalueAt.

Comment: Ok, obrigado, vou tentar aqui