# Colocar uma tabela criada em um container já existente

Tags: java, swing, jtable

preciso de ajuda!

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação na faculdade que utilizará o BubbleSort - sim! Tivemos o azar de pegar esse! - para sortear alguns dados dentro de uma tabela.

Eu criei a tabela por meio de uma classe que extendeu AbstractTableModel, porém eu não consigo fazê-la ficar no jPanel que já criei com o Swing. 
Alguém sabe como resolver ?

https://github.com/irom-theprogrammer/ProgramaDengueV3

Nesse link está o projeto feito no netbeans - o código está meio bagunçado. Espero que entendam.

No pacote 'tabela' estão as classes de definição da tabela.
No pacote 'tela' está a classe TelaRegistrar - que é a classe no qual estou tentando colocar a tabela. Se baseiem nela.

Agradeço a atenção dos que poderem ajudar.

Comment: Você deve colocar a tabela dentro de um JScrollPane, e não dentro de um Jpanel.

Comment: A tabela está dentro do JPanel e este está dentro do JScrollPane.

Comment: Esta ordem está errada, jtables são componentes especiais que podem aumentar de tamanho conforme os dados contidos nela, devem ser colocados dentro de um container adaptavel, se não elas não vão exibir corretamente as colunas(não vai exibir cabecalho) e nem todas as linhas da tabela. Inverta esta ordem ai, a jtabel deve ser inserida direto no jscrollpane.

Comment: Não teria sido melhor colocar o código-fonte aqui? Não precisa tirar o link do github, mas colocar o código-fonte seria melhor. Além disso, sério que você quer usar BubbleSort? Com tanto algoritmo de ordenação por aí simples de implementar e bem melhor (MergeSort, QuickSort, `java.util.Arrays.sort(int[])`, etc), você pega justamente aquele que é considerado como sendo o exemplo padrão de um algoritmo ruim?

Comment: Executei o código e não vi problema. A table está sendo exibida normalmente.

Comment: Victor, foram dados vários tópicos e foi sorteado esse pra gente. Somos obrigados a usá-lo. E não coloquei o código, pois há várias classes e pacotes em níveis de herança e é melhor enxergarem isso. Entende?

Comment: Diego. Em relação a container adaptavel. Eu não tinha pensado nisso, mas de fato o jpanel corta a tabela quando ela está grande. Vou verificar isso também.
O código compila normal. O problema é que tá sendo gerado uma tabela (que é a feita em AbstractTableModel) fora da janela swing que criei. Então há duas tabelas ali. Eu preciso que a tabela nova fique no lugar da antiga.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No construtor `TelaRegistrar()`, logo abaixo de `initComponents()`, altere conforme abaixo:

```
public TelaRegistrar() {
        this.funcoes = new ArrayList<>();
//        this.tela = new ListaFuncoesView(funcoes);
//        tela.setVisible(true);

        initComponents();

        FuncaoModeloTabela mod = new FuncaoModeloTabela(funcoes);
        tblReg.setModel(mod);

}
```

Como você criou o próprio `TableModel` com a classe `Tabela`, basta passar a classe `FuncaoModeloTabela`(que parece complementar a classe `Tabela` ao estendê-la) através do método `suaTable.setModel(TableModel dataModel)`.

A classe `ListaFuncoesView` se torna desnecessária com esta mudança, já que a função dela era unicamente exibir a tabela numa tela a parte.

Outra dica importante é sempre adicionar uma `JTable` em um `JScrollPane`, assim o cabeçalho da sua tabela será exibido corretamente e, caso tenha muitas linhas, o container irá ajustar o scroll vertical automaticamente.

Comment: Ok. Fiz as alterações. Deletei o JPanel e coloquei o JTable direito no JScrollPane. Funcionou perfeitamente. Agradeço. =D
Agora só mais um probleminha: quando aperto em inserir, a tabela não aparece atualizada com a linha que coloco.

Comment: @IagoMello se a resposta te atendeu, você pode marcar como aceita clicando no `v`, assim servirá de referencia para outros com problemas semelhantes :)

Comment: Meu primeiro post aqui. hehe Foi marcado. Como faço pra resolver o problema de inserção da linha ?

Comment: @IagoMello bom, isso já é outra duvida diferente e careceria de outra pergunta(ou uma rápida pesquisa aqui você acha respostas já prontas). Uma delas é você adicionar uma linha vazia, como pode ser visto [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/125960/28595) ou adicionar um método `addRow` no seu tablemodel, que receba um objeto do tipo que a tabela trabalha. Se isso não for bem o que precisa, ai você precisa fazer outra pergunta, adicionando um [mcve].

Comment: Agradecido. Vou verificar os links e tentar ser mais claro em uma próxima. Abraços.