# Atualizar JTable usando DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Entendo que é quase abominável o uso do DefaultTableModel, porém, utilizei este modelo e agora estou sem tempo para alterar para um TableModel (que eu não aprendi a usar ainda), há alguma forma de atualizar uma tabela de uma classe na View, após um método de create no Dao? O Sistema é em Java, utilizando Javax.Swing MVC.

**Criação da tela principal e dados da JTable**

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource().equals(btnentrar)) {

        if (txtsenha.getPassword().length == 0 || txtuser.getPassword().length == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Preencha os campos");
        } else {

            UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario = userDao.Login(new String(txtuser.getPassword()), new String(txtsenha.getPassword()));

            if (usuario != null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Conectado");
                Principal principal = new Principal();
                principal.initComponents(usuario);
                principal.carregarDadosProdutosJTable();
                frame.dispose();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Não foi possível efetuar login.");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Package:View Classe:Login

Uma tela simples de login, essa é a ação do botão Entrar.

**Método para carregar os dados na JTable**

```
public void carregarDadosProdutosJTable() {
    ItemDao itemDao = new ItemDao();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    ArrayList<Item> itens = (ArrayList<Item>) itemDao.listarProdutos();
    for (Item c : itens) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{c.getCodigo(), c.getDescricao(), c.getCategoria(), c.getEstoque()});
    }
}
```

Package:View Classe:Principal

Se eu tentar apenas chamar esse método novamente, o NetBeans exibe um erro de Null na terceira linha desse código (DefaulTableModel model = ...)

**Método salvar novo Item**

```
public void salvarItem(Item item) {
    try {
        // cria um preparedStatement
        pstm = con.prepareStatement("insert into produto (prodescricao,procategoria,proestoque) values (?,?,?)");

        pstm.setString(1, item.getDescricao());
        pstm.setString(2, item.getCategoria());
        pstm.setInt(3, item.getEstoque());
        pstm.execute();
        pstm.close();
        con.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item registrado com sucesso.");
    } catch (SQLException erro) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro de sql " + erro.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Package:Dao Classe:ItemDao

O ideal, acho que seria fazer a atualização após salvar um novo item, visto que alteraria a lista de produtos, ou itens, e a antiga tabela não seria mais a correta. Há alguma forma de fazer isso sem precisar implementar um TableModel? Estou ciente do quão melhor é utilizar um TableModel, porém, não estou com muito tempo nesse projeto para isso. Sou iniciante na área, se puderem simplificar a explicação agradeço.

Comment: Faça como vc disse, após salvar os dados chame o método `carregarDadosProdutosJTable()`

Comment: @DiegoAugusto "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" na linha "DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();" do método CarregarDadosProdutosJTable()

Comment: Vc tá chamando esse método na view né?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto na criação da JTable eu chamo na view, após o Login, a atualização eu tentei chamar no Dao, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Vc tem um botão que faz o salvar certo? Esse botão tem uma ação, chame ele após o salvar dentro do action do botão

Comment: @DiegoAugusto O mesmo erro.

Comment: Antes de chamar o método `carregarDadosProdutosJTable()` sua tabela tem algo carregado ou esse método é quem deveria carregar?

Comment: @diegofm Após a validação do Login eu chamo o initComponents() para criar a tela, e logo em seguida o carregadDadosProdutosJTabel() para carregar a tabela. Está funcionando, o problema é atualizar ela.

Comment: Não estou entendendo seu problema, a pergunta não deixa clara onde é a origem do erro. Alias, ela diz sim, mas você nos comentários está dizendo outra coisa. Em que momento o nullpointer acontece?

Comment: @diegofm Eu tenho uma tabela, e preciso atualizar ela. Pesquisando achei algumas formas, mas todas são com o TableModel, que eu não estou usando, mesmo sabendo que é melhor. Queria saber se há uma forma de atualizar essa tabela usando o DefaultTableModel.

Comment: Sem tablemodel, impossivel. Se eu entendi bem, o método problemático carrega a tabela, mas se chamado uma segunda vez, ele acusa erro?  Ta dificil te ajudar, ainda mais sem um [mcve] para poder ou simular o problema ou analisar melhor o funcionamento do seu programa.

Comment: @diegofm é exatamente isso, inicialmente ele funciona, mas se tentar chamar novamente tem o problema. Tem como marcar um comentário como resposta?

Comment: Tem não, já resolveu o problema?

Comment: @diegofm Era uma dúvida, queria saber se havia alguma forma, se não tem, já consegui minha resposta.

Comment: Gabriel, sua tabela é tão complexa assim? Criar um tablemodel é mais simples do que parece, [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121513/28595) eu explico passo-a-passo como criar um, é bem simples. Talvez seja até melhor perder um tempinho criando um, do que ter dor de cabeça e perder um tempão depois dando manutenção. E qualquer dúvida, você pode questionar aqui no site também. :)

Comment: @diegofm haha, é a cabeça dura que não deixa mesmo, mas pelas inúmeras limitações do DefaultTableModel vou precisar do TableModel mesmo. Obrigado pelas orientações.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, recomendo a declarar o modelo da JTable na class, assim sempre que precisar basta fazer `table.getModel(model)`
O erro deve-se a não ter declarado a JTable no construtor (`public (classe utilizada)`) 
Na class deve fazer `DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(String[](Seus campos)` e no construtor faça `(nomedatabela) = new JTable(model)`
Isso deve resolver o problema. Caso não resolva, peço impensa desculpa mas também sou iniciante

`

Answer (score -2):

```
public void carregarDadosProdutosJTable() {
    ItemDao itemDao = new ItemDao();

    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(4);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(220);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(40);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(40);            
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    ArrayList<Item> itens = (ArrayList<Item>) itemDao.listarProdutos();

    try{
        for (Item c : itens) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{c.getCodigo(), c.getDescricao(), c.getCategoria(), c.getEstoque()});
    }
    }catch(Exception erro){
        erro.printStackTrace();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A tabela não pôde ser carregada");
     }
}
```

Veja qual erro aparecerá, ou coisa, posta seu método que lista os itens

Comment: Creio que isso não tem nada a ver com o problema.