# Deixar apenas uma coluna do JTable editável

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Tenho meu modelo de dados que fiz pra testes como mostra o código abaixo:

```
public class ModeloDados {

    private String nome;
    private String sobreNome;
    private String telefone;

    public ModeloDados(String nome, String sN, String fn){
        this.nome=nome;
        this.sobreNome=sN;
        this.telefone=fn;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nome
     */
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    /**
     * @param nome the nome to set
     */
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    /**
     * @return the sobreNome
     */
    public String getSobreNome() {
        return sobreNome;
    }

    /**
     * @param sobreNome the sobreNome to set
     */
    public void setSobreNome(String sobreNome) {
        this.sobreNome = sobreNome;
    }

    /**
     * @return the telefone
     */
    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    /**
     * @param telefone the telefone to set
     */
    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

}
```

E montei tambem uma classe com o `AbstractTableModel`, que seria o modelo de tabela:

```
public class tabelaPrincipal extends AbstractTableModel {

    private ArrayList linhas = null;
    private String[] colunas = null;

    public tabelaPrincipal(ArrayList lin, String[] col) {
        setLinhas(lin);
        setColunas(col);

    }

    public ArrayList getLinhas() {
        return linhas;
    }

    public void setLinhas(ArrayList dados) {
        linhas = dados;
    }

    public String[] getColunas() {
        return colunas;
    }

    public void setColunas(String[] nomes) {
        colunas = nomes;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        //retorna a quantidade de colunas(conta a quantidade e retorna)
        return colunas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        //retorna o tamanho do array(quantos letras tem)
        return linhas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int numCol) {
        return colunas[numCol];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int numLin, int numCol) {
        Object[] linha = (Object[]) getLinhas().get(numLin);
        return linha[numCol];
    }


    public boolean isCellEditabel(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
        return true;
    }
}
```

E dentro de um Form criei um evento que a clicar que preenche a `JTable`, com valores de teste.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O evento que criei ficou assim

```
ModeloDados d1 = new ModeloDados("Valdecir", "Padovani", "AAAA");
    ModeloDados d2 = new ModeloDados("João", "Silva", "BBBB");
    ModeloDados d3 = new ModeloDados("Jose","Martins","CCCC");

    ArrayList array = new ArrayList<>();

    array.add(new Object[]{d1.getNome(),d1.getSobreNome(),d1.getTelefone()});
    array.add(new Object[]{d2.getNome(),d2.getSobreNome(),d2.getTelefone()});
    array.add(new Object[]{d3.getNome(),d3.getSobreNome(),d3.getTelefone()});

    String[] colunas = {"NOME","SOBRE NOME","NUMERO"};

    tabelaPrincipal modeloTabela = new tabelaPrincipal(array, colunas);
    jTable1.setModel(modeloTabela);
```

Gostaria deixar uma coluna editável, como por exemplo a ultima que seria para o usuário editar o telefone.
Porém não estou conseguindo deixar a coluna editável será que alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando seu código como ponto de partida, onde a tabela aparenta ter apenas 3 colunas, altere seu método desta forma:

```
public boolean isCellEditabel(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
    return columnIndex == 2;
}
```

Lembrando que você precisará também implementar o método [**`setValueAt()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#setValueAt-java.lang.Object-int-int-) herdado da classe `AbstractTableModel`.

Caso tenha dúvidas quanto a implementação, [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121513/como-popular-uma-jtable-com-tablemodel-pr%C3%B3prio) há instruções completas da implementação de um tablemodel próprio.

---

O `setValueAt()` poderia ser algo desta forma:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

   Object[] linha = (Object[]) getLinhas().get(rowIndex);
   linha[columnIndex] = aValue;
   //este método é quem notifica a mudança do model na tabela
   fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Comment: Eu precisava deixar dinâmico esse isCellEditabel, pra quando for chamado só passar a coluna pra que se torne editável.

Comment: @Valdecir não entendi sua duvida, como assim dinamico? Na pergunta você diz que precisa deixar a ultima coluna editavel, dessa forma, ela vai ficar editavel.

Comment: sim, mas essa classe é uma classe de teste... Suponhamos que precisaria deixar outras tabelas editáveis em diferentes colunas

Comment: @Valdecir este comentário apresenta uma duvida diferente da que foi perguntada. Você questionou como deixar apenas uma coluna editável, e deu como exemplo a terceira coluna de uma tabela com 3. A resposta é justamente para este problema apresentado na pergunta. E para esta outra dúvida, você quer aplicar a classe pra diferentes tabelas, não é interessante fazer isso, além de ser complicado, mais fácil criar um model pra cada uma e tratar as colunas conforme a resposta orientou.

Comment: Entendi, realmente fica melhor fazer específico... Estou fazendo exatamente como está acima mas não consegui implementar o setValueAt(), poderia me dar uma força?

Comment: @Valdecir posso sim, mas o código da pergunta linkada no final resposta não lhe ajudou? Lá tem um código completo e pronto para exemplificar, e tem a implementação do tablemodel com este método, se mesmo aquele código não ajudar, comenta aqui o problema que tiver enfrentando na hora de implementar.

Comment: Então eu sou novo nesse esquema de jTable, consegui popular ela totalmente e esta editável. Porem tenho que implementar o setValueAt() para que as edições sejam aceitas. A explicação linkada você cria um tipo  funcionário para inserir os dados e eu estou trabalhando diferente passo um vetor de objetos como deveria proceder?

Comment: @Valdecir tenta dessa forma: http://pastebin.com/5b1G41Kk

Comment: Perfeito... Obrigado peja ajuda!!!