# Como fazer com que os valores do JTable sejam os mesmos do ArrayList<Pessoa>?

Tags: java, swing, lista, jtable

Possuo um exemplo de programa que adiciona objetos do tipo da minha classe `Pessoa` em um `JTable` e também num `ArrayList<T>`, este programa possui três funcionalidades básicas que são as seguintes:

1. Adicionar
2. Alterar
3. Apagar

Veja a imagem do programa:

[image: Tela do programa exemplo]

No evento de clique do botão <kbd>Add</kbd> é adicionado um objeto de tipo `Pessoa` no `JTable` e também em um `ArrayList<T>` de tipo desta classe, veja:

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Pessoa pessoaAdd = new Pessoa(txtNome.getText(), obtemIdAtual(tablePessoas));
    listaPessoas.add(pessoaAdd);
    addPessoaToJTable(tablePessoas, pessoaAdd);
}
```

Repare que existe o método `obtemIdAtual()` que é responsável por gerar o `id` de forma sequencial, e tanto quanto os valores dos objetos armazenados na variável `listaPessoas` e os valores adicionados ao `JTable` `tablePessoas` são idênticos.

## Reproduzindo o exemplo

Para reproduzir este exemplo você vai precisar do código da classe Pessoa e também do código correspondente a tela do programa, são dois arquivos. Seguem os códigos completos abaixo.

Código da classe **Pessoa**:

```
package aquicolocaseupacote;

public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    public String getNome() { return nome; }
    public void setNome(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }
    
    private int id;
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    
    public Pessoa() { }
    
    public Pessoa(String nome, int id) {
        this.nome = nome; 
        this.id = id; 
    }
}
```

Código da tela **MainExemplo**:

```
package aquicolocaseupacote;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MainExemplo extends JFrame {
    private List<Pessoa> listaPessoas = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public MainExemplo() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        btnApagar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnAlterar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnAdd = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tablePessoas = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtNome = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Exemplo");
        setResizable(false);

        btnApagar.setText("Apagar");
        btnApagar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnApagarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnAlterar.setText("Alterar");
        btnAlterar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAlterarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnAdd.setText("Add");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAddActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        tablePessoas.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Id", "Nome"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tablePessoas);

        jLabel1.setText("Nome:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(btnAdd)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(btnAlterar)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(btnApagar)
                                .addGap(0, 46, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(txtNome)))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(txtNome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnApagar)
                    .addComponent(btnAlterar)
                    .addComponent(btnAdd))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        Pessoa pessoaAdd = new Pessoa(txtNome.getText(), obtemIdAtual(tablePessoas));
        listaPessoas.add(pessoaAdd);
        addPessoaToJTable(tablePessoas, pessoaAdd);
    }                                      

    private void btnAlterarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        switch (btnAlterar.getText()) {
            case "Alterar":
                btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
                btnAlterar.setText("Salvar");
                break;
            case "Salvar":
                btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
                btnAlterar.setText("Alterar");
                break;
        }
    }                                          

    private void btnApagarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        
    }                                         
    
    void addPessoaToJTable(JTable jTable, Pessoa pessoa) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();        
        model.addRow(new Object[] { pessoa.getId(), pessoa.getNome() });
    }
    
    int obtemIdAtual(JTable jTable) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
        
        if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
            return  (Integer) model.getValueAt(model.getRowCount() - 1, 0) + 1;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {                      
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> { 
            new MainExemplo().setVisible(true); 
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAdd;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAlterar;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnApagar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable tablePessoas;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtNome;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

---

## Minha dificuldade

Eu não estou conseguindo implementar a rotina do botão <kbd>Alterar</kbd> e nem do botão <kbd>Apagar</kbd>, ou seja, quando o usuário for fazer uma alteração clicando no botão de alteração o valor (objeto de tipo Pessoa) deve ser alterado tanto no objeto que esta na variável `listaPessoas` quanto no JTable `tablePessoas` e o mesmo vale para o botão de exclusão.

Eu gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer esta implementação de acordo com que esta descrito acima?

Comment: Eis a solução dos seus problemas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121513/como-popular-uma-jtable-com-tablemodel-pr%C3%B3prio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implemente os métodos `setValueAt()` e `getColumnClass` no *TableModel*, para que a `Jtable` saiba que tipo de dado exatamente há em cada coluna, e o que fazer com eles quando a tabela sofrer alteração.

Mas para tornar mais fácil a manutenção do código da sua tabela, o ideal seria criar um `TableModel` proprio ao invés de usar o `DefaultTableModel`, pois desta forma você abstrai da classe de sua tela e da propria tabela, funcionalidades ligadas ao model, como remover e adicionar novos objetos. Eu costumo sempre que preciso fazer uma tabela no [swing](/questions/tagged/swing), partir do padrão [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121514/28595) modificando ou adicionando o que eu precisar a mais.

Sendo assim, um model básico para seu objeto, poderia ser feito desta forma:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class PessoaTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private ArrayList<Pessoa> lista;
    private final int COLUNA_NOME = 1;
    private final int COLUNA_ID = 0;
    private String[] columns = {"id", "nome"};
    private boolean[] columnsCanEdit = {false, true};

    public PessoaTableModel() {
        this.lista = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return this.columns.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return columnsCanEdit[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case COLUNA_ID:
                return Integer.class;
            case COLUNA_NOME:
                return String.class;
            default:
                return String.class;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Pessoa p = this.lista.get(rowIndex);

        switch (columnIndex) {
            case COLUNA_NOME:
                return p.getNome();
            case COLUNA_ID:
                return p.getId();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        Pessoa p = this.lista.get(rowIndex);

        switch (columnIndex) {
            case COLUNA_NOME:
                p.setNome(String.valueOf(aValue));
                break;
            case COLUNA_ID:
                p.setId((int) aValue);
        }
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    //retornará o indice do objeto na lista do model
    private int indexOf(Pessoa p) {
        return this.lista.indexOf(p);
    }

    //adiciona um novo objeto e notifica os listerners da tabela
    public void addRow(Pessoa p) {
        this.lista.add(p);
        this.fireTableRowsInserted(this.indexOf(p), this.indexOf(p));
    }

    //remove um objeto do model pelo indice(linha) da tabela
    public void removeRow(int linha) {
        Pessoa p = this.lista.get(linha);
        this.lista.remove(linha);
        super.fireTableRowsDeleted(linha, linha);
    }
}
```

E depois, basta configurar o model para sua tabela na classe principal da sua *JTable*:

```
model = new PessoaTableModel();
tablePessoas.setModel(model);
```

No botão "Adicionar", você altera para que ele instancie um objeto pessoa e passe-o para o método do model:

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Pessoa pessoaAdd = new Pessoa(txtNome.getText(), model.getRowCount());
    model.addRow(pessoaAdd);

}
```

Para implementar a função de deleção, configure o botão de deletar desta forma:

```
private void btnApagarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    final int indiceRowModel = this.tablePessoas.getSelectedRow();
    model.removeRow(indiceRowModel);
}
```

Seu código com as alterações acima ficaria assim:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainExemplo extends JFrame {

    private PessoaTableModel model;

    public MainExemplo() {
        initComponents();
        model = new PessoaTableModel();
        tablePessoas.setModel(model);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        btnApagar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnAlterar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnAdd = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tablePessoas = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtNome = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Exemplo");
        setResizable(false);

        btnApagar.setText("Apagar");
        btnApagar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnApagarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnAlterar.setText("Alterar");
        btnAlterar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAlterarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnAdd.setText("Add");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAddActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tablePessoas);

        jLabel1.setText("Nome:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addContainerGap()
                                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addContainerGap()
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addComponent(btnAdd)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(btnAlterar)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(btnApagar)
                                                        .addGap(0, 46, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(txtNome)))))
                        .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addComponent(txtNome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(btnApagar)
                                .addComponent(btnAlterar)
                                .addComponent(btnAdd))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Pessoa pessoaAdd = new Pessoa(txtNome.getText(), model.getRowCount() + 1);
        model.addRow(pessoaAdd);

    }

    //não precisa mais deste método
    private void btnAlterarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
//        switch (btnAlterar.getText()) {
//            case "Alterar":
//                btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
//                btnAlterar.setText("Salvar");
//                break;
//            case "Salvar":
//                btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
//                btnAlterar.setText("Alterar");
//                break;
//        }
    }

    private void btnApagarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        //pega a localizacao da linha clicada
        final int indiceRowModel = this.tablePessoas.getSelectedRow();
        model.removeRow(indiceRowModel);
    }

    //não precisa mais deste método
//    int obtemIdAtual(JTable jTable) {
//        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
//
//        if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
//            return (Integer) model.getValueAt(model.getRowCount() - 1, 0) + 1;
//        } else {
//            return 1;
//        }
//    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new MainExemplo().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAdd;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAlterar;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnApagar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable tablePessoas;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtNome;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Particulamente eu não criaria uma função de alterar graficamente, já que o model e a tabela já podem fazer isso, graças a implementação do `setValueAt` combinado com o método `getColumnClass`, a não ser que haja algum requisito que exija essa separação.

Outro detalhe é que a implementação está bastante "crua" para que não tornasse o código e a resposta extenso demais e fugisse do que foi perguntado, pois precisa ser validado antes de apagar, se há algo selecionado na tabela para que não estoure `NullPointerException`no model, e dependendo da necessidade, verificar se o objeto a ser adicionado já não existe, etc.

Lembrando que os métodos que não estão comentados, estão explicados [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121514/28595) o que cada um deles faz no `TableModel`.