# Jtable em Java, erro de parametro?

Tags: java, jtable

Estou com dificuldades ao passar os *parâmetros* para meu `jTable`, sendo estes parâmetros um `Object[][]` e uma `String[]`.

```
tabela = new JTable(dados, colunas);
```

Ele não funciona os dados são uma matriz assim:

```
dados = new Object[1][contador_de_grupos];
```

E as colunas assim:

```
colunas[i] = "Grupo "+ i+1;
```

Onde os dados das colunas recebem os nomes dos grupos dentre de um laço de repetição, pois o `v=`**cabeçalho** não é estático vai aumentar ou diminuir de tamanho a depender do número de grupos criados no momento do cálculo

Comment: Que erro está dando?

Comment: Olha, se a intenção e ter colunas de tamanho dinamico, a sua abordagem está bem errada. Vetores SEMPRE precisam ter seu tamanho definidos, sejam  unidimensionais(ex.: `int[] vet`) ou multidimensionais(ex.: `int[][] matriz`). Você não pode passar um valor como dimensão que não esteja definido. Se quiser usar colunas dinamicas, você precisa [**criar seu próprio TableModel**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121514/28595).