# Carregando JTable e processador fica em alto processo

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, jtable

estou fazendo um sisteminha e nele tem uma `JTable` e eu preciso carregador meus dados, Fiquei analisando pelo gerenciador de tarefas que quando essa função de carregar a tabela é chamada, ela aumenta muito a carga do processador. O que pode ser? Já testei e tenho certeza que é por causa dessa função. Lembro que NÃO estou usando a `DefaultTableModel` e sim uma minha. Alguém sabe o motivo? Meu processador é um i5 6500.

Classe que contém o metodo de carregar a tabela, lembrando que estou usando o MVC, assim sendo, ele retorna um `ArrayList` que será usado na minha `TableModel`.

```
package lifetech.model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import lifetech.util.Conexao;

public class TarefasDataDAO {

    private Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
    private Connection conn = conexao.conectar();

    public ArrayList carregarTabela(String date) throws ParseException{

        ArrayList linhas = new ArrayList();

            //Formata a data que é passada por parametro, para conseguir pesquisar no banco de dados
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            java.sql.Date data = new java.sql.Date(format.parse(date).getTime());



        try{

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_tarefas WHERE data = ? ORDER BY id ASC";
            conexao.pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            conexao.pstm.setDate(1, data);
            conexao.rs = conexao.pstm.executeQuery();



            while(conexao.rs.next()){

                linhas.add(new Object[]{conexao.rs.getInt("id"),format.format(conexao.rs.getDate("data")),
                           conexao.rs.getString("titulo"), conexao.rs.getString("descricao"),
                           conexao.rs.getString("comeco"), conexao.rs.getString("termino"),
                           conexao.rs.getString("observacao"), conexao.rs.getString("status")});
            }

            return linhas;

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Erro ao preencher tabela de Tarefas da data " + date + "\n"
                                + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }finally{
            conexao.desconectar();
        }

    }
```

**TableModel**

```
package lifetech.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private ArrayList linhas;
    private String[] colunas;

    //Construtor

    public TableModel(ArrayList linhas, String[] colunas) {
        this.linhas = linhas;
        this.colunas = colunas;
    }

    //Metódos

    public String getColumnName(int numColumn){
        return this.colunas[numColumn];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return linhas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int numLinha, int numColuna) {
        Object[] linha = (Object[]) linhas.get(numLinha);
        return linha[numColuna];
    }

    //Getters e setters

    public ArrayList getLinhas() {
        return linhas;
    }

    public void setLinhas(ArrayList linhas) {
        this.linhas = linhas;
    }

    public String[] getColunas() {
        return colunas;
    }

    public void setColunas(String[] colunas) {
        this.colunas = colunas;
    }



}
```

Comment: Pode ser um inifinidade de coisas, nao tem como deduzir. Pode ser uma grande quantidade de dados, pode ser uma lógica mal escrita, etc. Não tem como chutar assim. Tenho uma app que carrega mais de 5000 linhas de um banco em uma jtable sem travamentos, pra você ver como isso é relativo. De qualquer forma, adicione um **[mcve]** contendo uma quantidade de dados pequena para que seja possivel simular e ver se o problema está no seu código.

Comment: Outra coisa, se você estiver executando sua aplicação pela IDE, seus testes fazem ainda menos sentido, porque a IDE também é uma aplicação que precisa de processamento.

Comment: Executei fora da IDE e funcionou dessa maneira descrita. Esse código que postei eu acho que é o necessário pois é ele quem carrega a minha JTable.

Comment: Infelizmente não da pra tirar nenhuma conclusão que possa te ajudar com esse código. Como eu disse, depende de uma infinidade de situações, que na maioria dos casos, só da pra chegar a algo testando. Apenas lendo este código, é quase impossivel te ajudar a resolver.

Comment: Entendo será que é por ser várias colunas?

Comment: Como eu disse, não dá pra afirmar se essa é a causa. Ah e o gerenciador de tarefas não é uma ferramenta adequada para se medir desempenho. A dica que eu lhe passo é pra não esquentar com isso, ainda mais se tratando de uma aplicação desktop do swing, que em breve nem receberá mais suporte. Em JavaFx, acredito que seja mais otimizado, se mesmo assim sentir que o desempenho está ruim, talvez seja uma boa mudar de tecnologia tambem.

Comment: O JDBC costuma da um pico de processamento quando se está conectando e desconectando em alguns bancos, mas em minha experiencia com swing e quantidades altas de dados em tabela, nunca foi significativo ao ponto de atrapalhar a aplicação. As vezes a preocupação com desempenho acaba sendo mais paranóia nossa do que um problema real :D

Comment: Beleza. Muito obrigado. Sei que não é muito certo fazer isso poraqui mas pode me passar algum link pra ver como javaFX funciona ou tutoriais.

Comment: Você diz que o problema é o swing e a `JTable`, que fez a sua própria `TableModel`, mas no final só dá o código do DAO?

Comment: Desculpa. Acabei de editar.

Comment: Criar um tablemodel para ficar fazendo cast de Object é um tremendo desperdicio. E a não ser que o Victor note algo que eu passei batido, ainda nao vi nada nos códigos que justifique lentidao que você está citando.

Comment: Como assim? Pode me explicar melhor oq quis dizer? Não entendi, sou novo em Java.

Comment: E qual seria a melhor solução então?

Comment: Eu fiz uma pergunta a respeito do uso de tablemodels, veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121513/28595 Sua principal utilidade é quando você tem objetos personalizados(POJO) para preencher a tabela, mas não quer ficar fazendo cast pra exibir. O tablemodel é poderoso, no exemplo simplista desse link, da pra fazer praticamente um CRUD completo direto na tabela.

Comment: Ok, entendo mas eu estou fazendo algo errado utilizando ele desta forma? Se sim, qual a melhor forma de se utilizar o tablemodel em meu caso?