# Incrementar quantidade de serviço igual

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Tenho uma tabela com o código do serviço, serviço, quantidade, valor e total. Quando eu adiciono na tabela um ITEM 1 por exemplo, os dados deste serviço serão adicionados na tabela. Mas caso eu adicione novamente este mesmo ITEM 1 na tabela,  queria que fosse incrementado a quantidade que o usuário fosse digitar e não criar uma nova linha repetindo, ITEM 1 e ITEM 1. segue abaixo o meu código para adicionar na tabela.

Sei que tenho que fazer um loop para percorrer as linhas da tabela e dentro do loop verificar se a linha da iteração atual possui o Item que está sendo adicionado.
Se possuir, você incrementa a quantidade desse Item e dá um `return;` pra sair do método. Caso o item ainda não exista na tabela, o loop irá percorrer todas as linhas e a execução irá sair do loop, após sair do loop você adiciona o novo Item.

Mas como fazer isto pela Jtable?

```
private void insereItem()
{
    if (txtQtde.getValue().equals(0))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Informe uma quantidade para adicionar o serviço na tabela", "Atenção", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        txtQtde.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    } else
    {
        try
        {
            txtQtde.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY));
            DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tbOs.getModel();
            String valUni = txtValor.getText().replace("R$", "").replace(" ", "").replace(".", "").replace(",", ".");
            double vtt = Double.parseDouble(valUni) * Integer.parseInt(txtQtde.getValue().toString());

            String total = String.valueOf(vtt);
            if (total.substring(total.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).length() < 2)
            {
                total = total + "0";
            }
            String unitario = txtValor.getText().replace("R$", "").replace(" ", "").replace(".", "").replace(",", ".");
            if (unitario.substring(unitario.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).length() < 2)
            {
                unitario = unitario + "0";
            }
            Object[] linha =
            {
                txtCodigoServico.getText(), cbbServico.getSelectedItem(), txtQtde.getValue().toString(), unitario, total
            };

            modelo.addRow(linha);

            double valorSubTotal = vtt + Double.parseDouble(txtSubTotal.getText().replace("R$", "").replace(" ", "").replace(".", "").replace(",", "."));
            setValorSubTotal(valorSubTotal);
            tbOs.setModel(modelo);
            atualizaSoma();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, adicione um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel executar o código e simular o problema.

Comment: Já te adianto que você provavelmente vai precisar escrever [seu próprio TableModel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121513/28595) e controlar nele este comportamento.