# Como concatenar condições em várias linhas?

Tags: asp

Estou trabalhando com um sistema legado e ele possui alguns IF's com muitas condições, com a intenção de melhorar a legibilidade do código tentei quebrar essas condições em diversas linhas..

```
If rs(0) = "Visualizar NF" 
  And Session("idPerfil") <> "19" 
  And Session("idPerfil") <> "10" 
Then
```

O trecho acima gera o seguinte erro:

```
Erro de compilação do Microsoft VBScript erro '800a03f9' 

'Then' esperado
```

Gostaria de saber como no ASP 3.0 podemos concatenar diversas condições em estruturas de decisão ou laços de repetição?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ASP Clássico espera o `Then` no final da mesma linha para interpretar o fim da condição, para concatenar as condições em diversas linhas precisamos utilizar o `_`.

Adicionando o underline `_` ao final de cada linha o código será interpretado corretamente.

Exemplo:

```
If rs(0) = "Visualizar NF" _
  And Session("idPerfil") <> "19" _
  And Session("idPerfil") <> "10" 
Then
```

Comment: isso é uma pergunta com auto-resposta? qual o propósito? ganhar medalha?

Comment: Bom eu tinha essa dúvida pesquisei e achei que poderia ser a dúvida de outros, acho que o propósito do stack é compartilhar conhecimento e  não ganhar medalhas..

Comment: @RicardoPontual é perfeitamente aceitável(e o site até incentiva) que se responda a propria pergunta, caso você não obtenha respostas, ou que as respostas, mesmo sendo uteis, não levem a resolução direta do problema. Recomendo a leitura [**deste link**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422/28595).

Comment: sim @Articuno isso eu sei, agora perguntar e responder no mesmo instante é no mínimo "estranho". Quando vi, a pergunta tinha side feita 15min antes e a resposta também, acho nem deu tempo, mas como disse, o site permite.

Comment: @RicardoPontual qual o problema? Se você tem uma questão util que já sabe a resposta, por que esperar pra responder? Veja um exemplo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121513/28595), eu fiz essa pergunta que eu já sabia a solução, então postei os dois juntos. Não há problema nisso, DESDE QUE haja realmente algo util a se compartilhar. :)

Comment: Problema nenhum @Articuno, é que nesse caso me parece mais documentação do que uma questão, já que eu já tenho a resposta. Acho que isso ficaria legal da Documentação do *Stackoverflow*, pena que infelizmente nesse momento essa funcionalidade só tem em inglês :-(