# Pegar linha da JTable após Filtrar Dados

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Estou usando uma `TableModel`(não o `DefaultTableModel`) que populo com dados do `banco` (`MySQL`), também uso uma Classe para fazer o filtro através do que digito em um `JTextField`.
Está funcionando corretamente, porém gostaria de, depois de realizar a filtragem através dos dados inseridos no `JTextField` poder selecionar somente os dados que "restaram" na `JTable`. Pois até o momento eu seleciono a primeira linha após o filtro,e tenho como retorno a primeira linha do modelo original ( através do evento `mouseClicked`). A imagem abaixo ilustra, talvez, de forma mais clara:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que tenha que, de alguma forma "criar um novo `modelo` com os dados resultantes após o filtro". Alguém pode ajudar a adaptar esta mesma classe, ou com informações de forma que eu possa alcançar meu objetivo?
Muito obrigado!

Classe para fazer o filtro:

```
package Converter;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Converter;


public class RowSorterToStringConverter extends Converter {

    private JTable table;

    public JTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public void setTable(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertForward(Object value) {
        return value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertReverse(Object mask) {
        TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter(table.getModel());

        String m = mask.toString();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++) {
            char c = m.charAt(i);
            sb.append('[').append(Character.toLowerCase(c)).append(Character.toUpperCase(c)).append(']');
        }
        sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(".*" + sb + ".*"));
        return sorter;
    }
}
```

Vinculação do `JTextField` com  a `Classe` `RowSorter`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Evento do mouse:

```
private void jtableCLicked() {
        saveButton.setEnabled(false);
        Condutor condutor = modelo.getCondutor(jTableCondutor.getSelectedRow());
        condutorIdField.setText((String.valueOf(condutor.getId())));
        condutorNomeField.setText(condutor.getNome());
        jCSetorDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getSetor());
        jCPessoaDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getPessoa());
        jCEmpresaDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getEmpresa());
        jCStatusDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getStatus());
        botoesEdicao();

    }
```

---

**Update:**

Fiz as seguintes alterações:

```
 private void jTextFieldBuscaKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                            
        String stringBusca = jTextFieldBusca.getText();
        filter(stringBusca);
    }                                           
    private void filter(String stringBusca) {
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(modelo);
        jTableCondutor.setRowSorter(tr);
        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(stringBusca));
    }

    private void jtableCLicked() {
        if (jTableCondutor.getRowSorter() != null) {
            try {
                int rowSel = jTableCondutor.getSelectedRow();
                int indexRowModel = jTableCondutor.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(rowSel);
                Condutor condutor = modelo.getCondutor(indexRowModel);
                condutorIdField.setText((String.valueOf(condutor.getId())));
                condutorNomeField.setText(condutor.getNome());
                jCSetorDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getSetor());
                jCPessoaDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getPessoa());
                jCEmpresaDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getEmpresa());
                jCStatusDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getStatus());
                botoesEdicao();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erro " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        else{
            try{
             Condutor condutor = modelo.getCondutor(jTableCondutor.getSelectedRow());
                condutorIdField.setText((String.valueOf(condutor.getId())));
                condutorNomeField.setText(condutor.getNome());
                jCSetorDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getSetor());
                jCPessoaDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getPessoa());
                jCEmpresaDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getEmpresa());
                jCStatusDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getStatus());
                botoesEdicao();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erro " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Agora está tudo da forma que eu precisava, exceto que, após realizar um filtro, neste caso permanecem apenas "algumas linhas na `JTable` ,"se eu editar uma linha (um `objeto` Condutor) ocorre a exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:invalid range
```

Após editar chamo estes dois métodos:

```
 public void limpaLista() {
        if (condutores.size() > 0) {
            int i = condutores.size();
            condutores.clear();
            fireTableRowsDeleted(0, i - 1);
        }
    }

public void preencherTabela() {
        CondutorDao condutorDao = new CondutorDao();
        modelo.adicionaLista(condutorDao.consultarCondutores());
    }
```

---

**Update 2:**

Criei estes trechos de código:

```
 private void jTBuscarRegistroKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                             
        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + jTBuscarRegistro.getText()));
    }                                            

    class MyListSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
            if (!lsm.isSelectionEmpty()) {

                try {
                    int rowSel = jTableCondutor.getSelectedRow();
                    int indexRowModel = jTableCondutor.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(rowSel);
                    Condutor condutor = modelo.getCondutor(indexRowModel);
                    condutorIdField.setText((String.valueOf(condutor.getId())));
                    condutorNomeField.setText(condutor.getNome());
                    jCSetorDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getSetor());
                    jCPessoaDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getPessoa());
                    jCEmpresaDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getEmpresa());
                    jCStatusDescr.setSelectedItem(condutor.getStatus());
                    botoesEdicao();
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    System.out.println("Erro Ao Carregar Dados " + ee.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }
    ;

    }
```

E no construtor:

```
jTableCondutor.setRowSorter(tr);
        jTableCondutor.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new MyListSelectionListener());
```

Agora funcionou corretamente, sem `Exception`, podendo selecionar após o filtro, e quando limpa o `JTextField` da busca, retorna o modelo original com as mudanças feitas nas linhas.

Comment: [Nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111258/atualizar-uma-jtable-que-est%C3%A1-numa-jframe-a-partir-de-um-jdialog/111408#111408) eu explico algo parecido, veja se consegue entender e adaptar. Caso não consiga, adicione um [mcve] para que seja possível tentar criar algo testável para o código postado.

Comment: Apenas para ver se eu lhe entendi, neste post que você indicou trata o caso de selecionar a linha após fazer o filtro, pois no meu código está fazendo a busca corretamente, apenas não consigo selecionar os dados após o filtro, seleciona sempre dados conforme o modelo carregado na primeira vez. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para recuperar a linha selecionada em uma `JTable`, você precisa chamar o método [`convertRowIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int)), passando o índice da linha selecionada na tabela como parâmetro, algo assim:

```
int rowSel = suaTable.getSelectedRow();//pega o indice da linha na tabela
int indexRowModel = suaTable.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(rowSel);//converte pro indice do model
```

Desta forma você evita problemas com `IndexOfBoundException` ao tentar manipular indices de linhas da tabela.

Supondo que `modelo.getCondutor` seja algum método do seu `TableModel` que recupere um objeto a partir do índice passado, passe o `indexRowModel` como parâmetro:

```
private void jtableCLicked() {
        ...

        int rowSel = suaTable.getSelectedRow();
        int indexRowModel = suaTable.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(rowSel);
        Condutor condutor = modelo.getCondutor(indexRowModel);

        ...
    }
```

---

Como você quer pegar a linha selecionada na medida em que alguma for selecionada na tabela, ao invés de usar um *listener* de cliques do mouse que pode não funcionar se o usuário alterar a linha selecionada via o teclado, uma solução melhor é sobrescrever o método [`valueChanged`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html#valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent)), adicionando um `ListSelectionlistener` à sua tabela:

```
suaTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource(); 

        if(!lsm.isSelectionEmpty()){

        //aqui você insere a ação que quer fazer quando
        //uma linha for selecionada ou uma seleção for
        //alterada na tabela
        }
    }
}
```

Desta forma, se uma seleção for feita ou alterada, independente se foi realizada por clique do mouse ou pelas setas do teclado, vai chamar este método.

**Referência:**

[How to Write a List Selection Listener(oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Comment: Entendi, preciso criar um `rowSorter`ou continuo a usar a classe que já utilizava? Pois recebo `null` aqui:   `int indexRowModel = jTableCondutor.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(rowSel);`ao tentar executar.

Comment: @Rodrigo no seu código, o método `convertReverse` retorna um TableRowSorter, você está atribuindo pra sua tabela este rowsorter? Se não tiver atribuido, vai retornar null mesmo.

Comment: @ diegofm , Eu fiz assim: tenho a classe `rowSorterToStringConverter`, arrastei para o `form`, vinculei o `jTextfield` a esse rowSorter` para poder fazer o "filter". Nas propriedades do `rowSorterToStringConverter` na opção `table`vinculei a `jTableCondutor`.

Comment: Fiz algum progresso, poderia vrificar meu update acima?Grato.

Comment: @Rodrigo pra que o else? Se você aplicar um Rowsorter e quando clicar numa linha, retornar nulo, é porque tem algum outro problema no seu código. Sem converter o indice como expliquei na resposta, este tipo de erro está sujeito a acontecer, já que o indice da view(tabela) nem sempre é o mesmo do model. Sem contar no risco de você editar um objeto totalmente diferente do selecionado. Se possivel, informe um [mcve] para que seja possivel testar e reproduzir o problema.

Comment: @ diegofm adicionei trechos de código, creio que está resolvido A menos que tenha feito de forma não aconselhavel.

Comment: @Rodrigo dentro do selectionListener funciona sem o erro de range? Eu acho que o problema era no else mesmo, pois lá, você estava pegando indice da view, e passando pro model. Quando você filtra, o indice muda pra view, por isso o erro. Aplique o rowsorter sempre na inicialização da tabela, dai quando o filtro for feito, o rowsorter não retornará nulo. Perceba que, usando evento de clique, até se clicar o header da tabela, vai entrar no método(o que pode ser a causa do problem anterior), mas no selection, só vai entrar se for selecionada alguma linha.

Comment: @ diegofm Sim, sem o erro do Range. Também alterei o evento do `jTBuscarRegistro` de `keyReleased` para  `jTBuscarRegistro.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener());`, pois com o `evento` não recarregava o `model`na `jTable` quando pressionava o botão "`limparjTBuscarRegistro`". Agora está tudo funcionando corretamente (claro que ainda tem muito a fazer neste projeto). Obrigado