# Verificar se chegou na ultima linha da tabela

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Estou usando esse código para fazer uma verificação de *aprovado* ou *reprovado*, mas quando ele chega na última linha, não está checando se está na última linha e não me dá o resultado.

Gostaria de saber como verificar se chegou na última linha da tabela.

```
   int coluna = CadresultadoTabela.getSelectedColumn();

    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
        int linha = CadresultadoTabela.getSelectedRow();
        Object obj = modelo.getValueAt(linha, 30);
        Object obj2 = modelo.getValueAt(linha, 31);
        Object obj3 = modelo.getValueAt(linha, 32);

        if ((obj == null || obj.toString().equals("")) && (obj2 == null || obj2.toString().equals(""))) {
            TabPreenchimento();
        } else {
            VerificarResultdo();
            if (modelo.getValueAt(linha, 33).equals("Reprovado")) {
                if (obj3 == null || modelo.getValueAt(linha, 32).equals("")) {
                    CadresultadoTabela.changeSelection(linha, 32, false, false);
                } else {
                    TabPreenchimento();
                }
            } else {
                TabPreenchimento();
            }
        }
    } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        int linha = CadresultadoTabela.getSelectedRow() - 1;
        Object obj = modelo.getValueAt(linha, 30);
        Object obj2 = modelo.getValueAt(linha, 31);
        Object obj3 = modelo.getValueAt(linha, 32);

        if ((obj == null || obj.toString().equals("")) && (obj2 == null || obj2.toString().equals(""))) {
            //VERIFICA SE A SELECAO ESTA NA ULTIMA LINHA
            if (CadresultadoTabela.getSelectedRow() != CadresultadoTabela.getRowCount()) {
                EnterPreenchimento();
            } else {
                TabPreenchimento();
            }
        } else {
            //VERIFICA SE A SELECAO ESTA NA ULTIMA LINHA
            if (CadresultadoTabela.getSelectedRow() != CadresultadoTabela.getRowCount()) {
                VerificarResultdoEnter();
            } else {
                VerificarResultdo();
            }
            if (modelo.getValueAt(linha, 33).equals("Reprovado")) {
                if (obj3 == null || modelo.getValueAt(linha, 32).equals("")) {
                    CadresultadoTabela.changeSelection(linha, 32, false, false);
                } else {
                    //VERIFICA SE A SELECAO ESTA NA ULTIMA LINHA
                    if (CadresultadoTabela.getSelectedRow() != CadresultadoTabela.getRowCount()) {
                        EnterPreenchimento();
                    } else {
                        TabPreenchimento();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //VERIFICA SE A SELECAO ESTA NA ULTIMA LINHA
                if (CadresultadoTabela.getSelectedRow() != CadresultadoTabela.getRowCount()) {
                    EnterPreenchimento();
                } else {
                    TabPreenchimento();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para verificar se a última linha está selecionada, você precisa comparar o índice da linha selecionada com `table.getRowCount() -1`, pois os índices começam em 0.

```
if(table.getSelectedRow() == table.getRowCount() -1){

    //ultima linha selecionada

}
```

Creio que no seu código, o jeito correto de checar isso algo assim:

```
if (CadresultadoTabela.getSelectedRow() == CadresultadoTabela.getRowCount() - 1)
```

Lembrando que se você tiver utilizando algum tipo de filtro na tabela(`RowSorter`), precisa [**converter o índice da seleção para o equivalente no model**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137744/28595).

Comment: Neste caso não funcionou não seria pq estou declarando        int linha = CadresultadoTabela.getSelectedRow() - 1;???

Comment: @Rafaaw não faço ideia, eu precisaria testar seu código para uma resposta mais especifica. No meu exemplo de teste esta forma funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Estranho, vou dar uma analisada e qualquer coisa entro em contato.