# Aplicar filtros em uma JTable

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtable, rowsorter

Eu tenho uma tabela e num Jpanel em cima dela criei uns textFields e combobox com a intenção de usa-los como filtro. O método:

```
tableRowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + busca));
```

Ele espera um string como filtro?
Se o filtro tiver mais de um parâmetro como faço utilizar ele?

A minha tela ta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seria algo assim como Exemplo:

```
public class teste2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

// Variaveis                
private javax.swing.JButton btnAplicar;
private javax.swing.JButton btnLimpar;
private javax.swing.JComboBox comboboxCategoria;
private javax.swing.JComboBox comboboxStatus;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblAbertura;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblCategoria;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblCliente;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblNumero;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblResponsavel;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblStatus;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblUsuario;
private javax.swing.JTable tableServicosAbertos;
private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField txtAbertura;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtCliente;
private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField txtNumero;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtResponsavel;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtUsuario;

public teste2() {
    iniciarComponentes();

}

private void iniciarComponentes() {

    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tableServicosAbertos = new javax.swing.JTable();
    comboboxStatus = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    lblCategoria = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblStatus = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtAbertura = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
    lblAbertura = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblUsuario = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblResponsavel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtUsuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtResponsavel = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    lblCliente = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtCliente = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtNumero = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
    lblNumero = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    comboboxCategoria = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    btnAplicar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnLimpar = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("SiGS - Sistema de gerenciamento de serviços");
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1366, 768));
    setResizable(false);
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {

        }
    });

    tableServicosAbertos.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][]{
                {"OS20160214", "SAS", "Redes", "20/11/2016", "Max Vargas", "Max Vargas", "Aberto"},
                {"OS20160242", "Multiserv", "Computadores", "15/07/2016", "Max Vargas", "Mateus Nascimento", "Fechado"},
                {"OS20165851", "Telecom", "CFTV", "16/07/2016", "Max Vargas", "Fabio Oliv.", "Fechado"},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String[]{
                "Numero", "Cliente", "Categoria", "Abertura", "Usuario", "Responável", "Status"
            }
    ));
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(tableServicosAbertos);

    comboboxStatus.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{" ", "Aberto", "Fechado", "Cancelado", "Pausado"}));

    lblCategoria.setText("Categoria:");

    lblStatus.setText("Status:");

    lblAbertura.setText(" Abertura:");

    lblUsuario.setText("Usuário:");

    lblResponsavel.setText("Responsável:");

    lblCliente.setText("Cliente:");

    lblNumero.setText("Número:");

    comboboxCategoria.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{" ", "Computadores", "CFTV", "Redes", "Telefonia", "Outros"}));

    btnAplicar.setText("OK");

    btnLimpar.setText("Limpar");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                                    .addComponent(lblStatus)
                                                    .addGap(15, 15, 15)
                                                    .addComponent(comboboxStatus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                    .addGap(85, 85, 85)
                                                    .addComponent(lblResponsavel)
                                                    .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                                                    .addComponent(txtResponsavel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 153, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                    .addComponent(lblCategoria)
                                                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                                                    .addComponent(comboboxCategoria, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                    .addGap(104, 104, 104)
                                                                    .addComponent(lblUsuario)
                                                                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                                                    .addComponent(txtUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 152, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                    .addComponent(lblAbertura)
                                                                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                                                    .addComponent(txtAbertura, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                    .addGap(105, 105, 105)
                                                                    .addComponent(lblCliente)
                                                                    .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                                                                    .addComponent(txtCliente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                                    .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                    .addComponent(btnAplicar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                    .addComponent(btnLimpar))
                                                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                    .addComponent(lblNumero)
                                                                    .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                                                                    .addComponent(txtNumero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                                    .addGap(78, 78, 78))
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                    .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(90, 90, 90)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(lblCategoria)
                                    .addComponent(comboboxCategoria, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(lblUsuario)
                            .addComponent(txtUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(lblNumero)
                            .addComponent(txtNumero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(lblStatus)
                            .addComponent(comboboxStatus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(lblResponsavel)
                            .addComponent(txtResponsavel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(lblAbertura)
                                            .addComponent(txtAbertura, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addComponent(lblCliente)
                                            .addComponent(txtCliente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                            .addComponent(btnAplicar)
                                            .addComponent(btnLimpar))))
                    .addContainerGap(241, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

Comment: Desculpe a demora, é que ao mesmo tempo que to tentando fazer esse filtro estou estudando  o Framework Quartz. 
É que minha tabela é montada em tempo de execução fazendo um select dos Serviços no banco utilizando uma biblioteca que peguei numa vídeo aula. Posto aqui a classe que faz isso + o select?

Comment: Max, seu código não está completo e ainda não é executável, alem de não tem os campos do print. Adicione a classe completa da sua tela, removendo esse método de chamada com o banco e classes personalizadas e adicionando esse trecho com dados manuais. Se não couber, poste no pastebin e adicione o link no fim da pergunta para conferencia.

Comment: Assim foi? Aqui tá ok. Desculpa. Primeira vez que posto algo aqui.

Comment: Você tentou executar esse código? Tente ai, ele não é executavel.

Comment: Agora Sim, como teste criei um arquivo Novo Arquivo Jframe, colei o código e rodei.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Após alguns testes, consegui desenvolver uma solução que fará a pesquisa de forma global, cobrindo eventuais falhas como quando um dos campos não é informado, e também limpando os filtros, quando todos os campos são apagados.

Inicialmente, você deve criar uma variável [**`TableRowSorter`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) como propriedade da classe, para ser usado na tabela posteriormente:

```
private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;
```

Pelo código, percebi que está criando a tela pelo editor do netbeans, então será necessário adicionar as linhas abaixo, que se referem a criação do `RowSorter`,  no construtor, após o método que cria a sua tabela(no caso, é o `iniciarComponentes();`):

```
//...

iniciarComponentes();

//resgata o TableModel da sua JTable
TableModel model = tableServicosAbertos.getModel();
//Cria um RowSorter baseado no TableModel resgatado
sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
//Aplica o RowSorte na na JTable
tableServicosAbertos.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

O método abaixo é quem fará todo o trabalho de filtragem na tabela, tratando cada campo de pesquisa pra coluna relativa na tabela:

```
protected void setFilterInJTable() {


    String  numero = txtNumero.getText().trim(),
            cliente = txtCliente.getText().trim(),
            categoria = comboboxCategoria.getSelectedItem().toString().trim(),
            abertura = txtAbertura.getText().trim(),
            usuario = txtUsuario.getText().trim(), 
            responsavel = txtResponsavel.getText().trim(),
            status = comboboxStatus.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

    //cria uma lista para guardar os filtros de cada coluna
    List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object, Object>>();
    filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + numero, 0));
    filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + cliente, 1));
    filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(categoria, 2));
    filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + abertura, 3));
    filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + usuario, 4));
    filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + responsavel, 5));
    filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(status, 6));
    //aplica os filtros no RowSorter que foi criado no construtor
    //utilizando o andFilter
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filters));

}
```

No botão `Aplicar`, basta adicionar um `ActionListener` e chamar o método `setFilterInJTable()` dentro do `actionPerformed`, que a pesquisa estará ativa.

Veja um print do resultado da pesquisa utilizando dos campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código do método acima pega todos os campos de filtro da tela como `String`, remove espaços em branco(para evitar resultados indesejados, caso um dos campos não seja informado), além de tratar as strings trazidas dos campos de texto como *[case insensitive](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case-sensitive)*.

Esse filtro pode até atender a sua tabela, mas há campos que não deveriam ser tratados como String, exemplo são os campos de data, se eles vem do banco como data, seus tipos deveriam ser mantidos na `JTable`.

Salientando o que foi dito na outra resposta, talvez o mais indicado é a pesquisa ser feita direto no banco, afinal, os dados da tabela podem ser modificados no banco por outras instancias da aplicação, e a pesquisa neste caso trabalhará com dados que pode não ser os mais atuais.

[Nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111408/28595) há alguns links de referência para estudo a respeito de `RowSorter`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, testei e funcionou muito bem. Só tenho que tentar ajeitar o meu código para ficar tudo ok, pois quando rodo agora ele não monta a tabela com o select e da erro de array estourado . Deve ter a ver com eu estar usando dafaultModel né? Vou procurar aprender a fazer meu próprio modelo.

Comment: @MaxVargas você pode marcar a resposta como aceita, clicando no `V` a esquerda dela, assim, ela serve de referencia, como a outra resposta serviu pra você =)

Answer (score 3):

Eu aconselharia sempre fazer a consulta diretamente no banco de dados, pelo simples fato de a qualquer minuto, as informações na tela podem ter sido atualizadas/deletadas e até mesmo inseridos novos registros.
Mas caso você queira utilizar o rowFilter, veja exemplo diretamente da documentação:

```
List< RowFilter < Object, Object > > rfs =  new ArrayList < RowFilter < Object, Object > >);
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)^Zac$"));
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)^A$"));
RowFilter af = RowFilter.andFilter(rfs);
```

Quando utilizei, lembro de ter problema com campos de data. Acredito que terá que fazer algo semelhante a isso:

```
RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, new Date());
```

Após isso, adicione o rowFilter a sua tabela. 
Qualquer dúvida, estou a disposição. (Faz tempo que não mexo com Jtable, qualquer erro, editem minha resposta ou me corrijam abaixo. Obrigado.

Comment: @diegofm Esqueci de mencionar o sorter. Testasse com ele também?

Comment: Poderia me situar mais ou menos como faria isso? Seria algo como um select usando um campo do filtro como parâmetro? ai eu faria 1 select para cada campo?