# Criando row filter "dinâmico"

Tags: java, swing, rowsorter

Eu estou usando `RowFilter` para criar filtros para determinadas colunas da minha tabela. A minha intenção é passar os componentes que eu quero utilizar como "barra" de pesquisa por paramento, criando eles dinamicamente, e da mesma forma aplicar filtros para eles, que correspondam a uma coluna da tabela, e por fim, poder combinar esses filtros caso seja necessário.

Eu criei um exemplo, em que eu possuo 4 colunas, eu quero poder filtrar as 3 primeiras colunas, podendo combinar os "campos" de filtragem.

Eu dei uma olhada nessa questão, [Aplicar filtros em uma JTable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166973/aplicar-filtros-em-uma-jtable/167044#167044), que é bem similiar ao que estou tentando fazer, porém neste caso ele passa filtros fixos.

O erro está ocorrendo quando tento capturar os textos dos filtros, ele me lança essa exceção:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at pesquisa.UmTeste.setaFiltrosPesquisa(UmTeste.java:96)
    at pesquisa.UmTeste.montaTela(UmTeste.java:64)
```

Obs 1: no exemplo eu estou tratando apenas componentes do tipo `JTextComponent`, sei que vou ter que fazer alterações para cobrir os demais componentes, além de, ter que tratar as colunas que não podem/devem ser tratadas com `strings`.

Obs 2: Tentei fazer o mais simples possível, apenas para ilustrar o problema, neste caso, os componentes estão de certa forma fixos, na questão de quantidade.

Meu exemplo:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class UmTeste extends JFrame {

    private String[] colunas = {"0", "1", "2", "3"};

    private Object[][] dados = {
        {"1", "Estados Unidos", "USA", "true"},
        {"2", "Canada", "CNA", "true"},
        {"3", "United Kingdom", "UN", "true"},
        {"4", "Germany", "GER", "true"},
        {"5", "France", "FRA", "true"}};

    private DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(dados, colunas);
    private JTable tabela = new JTable(dtm);

    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;
    private JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(tabela);

    private JComponent[] componentes = {new JTextField(), new JTextField(), new JTextField()};

    public UmTeste() {
        setTitle("Teste - RowFilter");
        add(montaTela());
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public JComponent montaTela() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //resgata o TableModel da sua JTable
        TableModel model = tabela.getModel();
        //Cria um RowSorter baseado no TableModel resgatado
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
        //Aplica o RowSorte na na JTable
        tabela.setRowSorter(sorter);

        painel.add(pesquisa(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        painel.add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setaFiltrosPesquisa();//seta o filtro
        return painel;
    }

    private JComponent pesquisa() {
        JPanel painelPesquisa = new JPanel();
        painelPesquisa.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        for (int i = 0; i < componentes.length; i++) {
            if (componentes[i] != null) {
                if (componentes[i] instanceof JTextComponent) {
                    painelPesquisa.add(new JLabel("Coluna " + i));
                    painelPesquisa.add(componentes[i]);
                    componentes[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 22));
                }
            }
        }
        return painelPesquisa;
    }

    private void setaFiltrosPesquisa() {
        String[] filtros = {""};
        for (int i = 0; i < componentes.length; i++) {
            if (componentes[i] != null) {
                if (componentes[i] instanceof JTextComponent) {
                    filtros[i] = ((JTextComponent) componentes[i]).getText().trim();
                }
                //cria uma lista para guardar os filtros de cada coluna
                List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filters = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int ii = 0; ii < filters.size(); i++) {
                    filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + filtros[i], ii));
                    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filters));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            UmTeste t = new UmTeste();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A causa do erro está nessa linha:

```
String[] filtros = {""};
```

Repare que você inicializa um array de String com apenas um indice vazio e tenta acessar ele com um índice baseado no tamanho de outro array diferente e maior.

Por esta razão estoura o `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, pois este array só possui um elemento, enquanto o array de `componentes` possui 3.

Se cada filtro deste array for equivalente a apenas um componente do outro, basta iniciar este com o mesmo tamanho do array de componentes:

```
String[] filtros = new String[componentes.length];
```

Há outros erros no seu código como configurar o rowFilter dentro do laço a cada vez que adiciona um filtro no `ArrayList`, mas foge ao foco da pergunta.

Comment: @GustavoSantos veja a edição.

Comment: "Há outros erros no seu código como configurar o rowFilter dentro do laço a cada vez que adiciona um filtro no ArrayList, mas foge ao foco da pergunta." não pode me explicar ? se for o caso eu posso editar a questão.

Comment: @GustavoSantos seu segundo laço está confuso, não da pra entender sua intenção com ele. Mas a linha `sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filters));` não tem nenhuma necessidade de ficar dentro de um laço.

Comment: é porque ele me retornava Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException, achei que deveria coloca - lo de acordo com os filtros.

Comment: @GustavoSantos você está criando uma lista de filtros vazia, esse for aparentemente nunca será executado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65379/discussion-between-articuno-and-gustavo-santos).