# Atualizar um Jtable dentro de um Jframe atraves de outro Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

Eu possuo um `JFrame`, onde dentro do mesmo tem um `JTable` e um `JButton` (Alterar) que faz a chamada de um outro JFrame. Neste outro JFrame, é realizado uma alteração dos dados de acordo com a linha selecionada na tabela e salvo no BD ao clicar em um JButton (Salvar).

Meu problema é que os dados não são atualizados automaticamente no meu JTable ao salvar a alteração, sendo assim, como faço a chamada de uma função de um JFrame que já está aberto?

Não funciona fazer o seguinte:

```
public class JFAltera extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ...
    private void jbSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        JFrameTabela jFrameTabela = new JFrameTabela();
        jFrameTabela.atualizaJTable();
    }
    ...
}

public class JFrameTabela extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ...
    public void atualizaJTable(){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Porque eu não quero instanciar um novo JFrame e sim chamar a função (public) de um JFrame que já está aberto.

Exemplo verificável das classe:

Classe JFrameTabela:

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JFrameTabela extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public JFrameTabela() {
        initComponents();
        readJTable(); // Atualiza os dados na tabela
    }

    public void readJTable(){

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();

        //Inicia a tabela com 0 linhas novamente
        tableModel.setNumRows(0);

        //Inserir 10 Linhas
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{
                "Teste 1",
                "Teste 2",
                "Teste 3",
                "Teste 4"
            });
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                        
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jbAlterar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable);

        jbAlterar.setText("Alterar");
        jbAlterar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jbAlterarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(226, 226, 226)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(426, 426, 426)
                        .addComponent(jbAlterar)))
                .addContainerGap(401, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addComponent(jbAlterar)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 70, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 228, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(89, 89, 89))
        );

        pack();
    }                      

    private void jbAlterarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        //Abro o meu JFrameAltera e envio os dados da linha selecionada
        JFrameAltera obj = new JFrameAltera();
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.preencheDados(jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(),0).toString(),
                jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(),1).toString(),
                jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(),2).toString(),
                jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(),3).toString());
    }                                         

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameTabela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameTabela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameTabela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameTabela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFrameTabela().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbAlterar;                 
}
```

Classe JFrameAltera:

```
public class JFrameAltera extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public JFrameAltera() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void preencheDados(String string1, String string2, String string3, String string4){

        //Preenche os campos com as informações das linha selecionada no "JFrameTabela"
        jf1.setText(string1);
        jf2.setText(string2);
        jf3.setText(string3);
        jf4.setText(string4);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jf1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jf2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jf3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jf4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jbSalvar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jbSalvar.setText("Salvar");
        jbSalvar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jbSalvarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(117, 117, 117)
                        .addComponent(jf1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                        .addComponent(jf2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                        .addComponent(jf3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jf4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(241, 241, 241)
                        .addComponent(jbSalvar)))
                .addContainerGap(458, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(69, 69, 69)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jf1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jf2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jf3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jf4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(63, 63, 63)
                .addComponent(jbSalvar)
                .addContainerGap(292, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }                      

    private void jbSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        //Aqui eu gravo as informações no BD (Funcionando)

        //***********É aqui que eu preciso chamar minha função "readJTable" do "JFrameTabela" que já está aberto.
    }                                        


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameAltera.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameAltera.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameAltera.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrameAltera.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFrameAltera().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton jbSalvar;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jf1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jf2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jf3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jf4;

}
```

Comment: Por favor, apresente um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar o problema e sugerir uma solução.

Comment: Relacionada(ou duplicata):[Atualizar uma Jtable que está numa JFrame a partir de um JDialog](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111258/atualizar-uma-jtable-que-est%C3%A1-numa-jframe-a-partir-de-um-jdialog)

Comment: Você disse `"nesse outro JFrame é realizado a alteração dos dados no BD"`, se você está misturando código de GUI com de BD (como por exemplo, colocar código que acede diretamente ao BD dentro de um actionPerformed() ) isso é considerado uma má prática (pelo que sei) e você poderá ter problemas com questões de acoplamento, violação do [DRY](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), etc.

Comment: Sem contar que se quer alterar dados de uma tela através de outra, usar 2 JFrames é uma abordagem muito errada. É exatamente para isso que existe JDialog, como sugerido na outra resposta.

Comment: `private void jbSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {` a menos que a linguagem tenha recursos novos que desconheço, esse método não está implementando o `actionPerformed()` porque o nome dele é diferente. Experimente colocar um `@Override` em cima dele e veja se aparece um erro na IDE. Além disso, pra escutar eventos sua classe teria que ser um `ActionListener`, e não vejo você implementando essa interface. Por último, pra você poder aceder a um JFrame instanciado, basta ter uma variável de instância (ou estática) com esse JFrame, e chamá-la depois.

Comment: @Douglas utilizar variaveis de componentes swing estáticas é uma pratica ruim. Componentes swing devem ser sempre manipulados dentro da EDT, sendo estática, isso pode causar problemas.

Comment: @Articuno Esse método é para fazer com que meus campos iniciem com o as informações da linha que foi selecionada na JFrameTabela

Comment: @Articuno no meu projeto estou trabalhando com Objeto, porém para versão verificável, fiz com String mesmo.

Comment: @LucasH.Rosa o ideal é você trabalhar com abstração, o que cada linha dessa tabela representa? Se tiver que ficar trocando dados e ter que ficar pegando campos de textos, seu código vai ficar uma bagunça danada.

Comment: @Articuno Cada linha dessa jTable representa um registro no meu banco de dados.

Comment: Bom vou tentar responder com o que dá pra responder, mas não garanto que possa servir pro seu código real, já que você não apresentou um exemplo dele, e sim um exemplo genérico totalmente diferente.

Comment: @Articuno Obrigado pela atenção, qualquer coisa me avisa que eu passo mais detalhes. Também posso postar o meu código aqui, porém como está com comunicação para o BD, não vai ser verificável, mas acredito que possa ajudar a entender o que eu quero fazer. Tentei chegar o mais próximo possível no exemplo verificável. VLW Abs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando se trabalha com mais de uma tela, o ideal é sempre utilizar apenas um `JFrame` como tela principal e criar [`JDialogs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) como telas secundárias, pois além da característica modal, você pode vincular todas ao Frame principal.

Como o código apresentado é muito genérico, vou tentar responder em cima dele. Seguindo a dica anterior, recomendo que altere a classe `JFrameAltera` para que seja um `JDialog` dependente da classe `JFrameTabela`, assim fica muito mais fácil trocar informações entre elas.

Então a assinatura da classe ficaria assim:

```
public class JFrameAltera extends javax.swing.JDialog {
```

Outro detalhe é que no botão que abre a nova janela, você está passando a sequencia entre 1 e 4 como número de colunas, quando na verdade a numeração de linhas e colunas em java começa sempre de 0, portanto, a numeração para 4 colunas vai de 0 a 3. Outro problema é que você não verifica se há realmente alguma linha selecionada na tabela antes de recuperar os dados, e isso vai estourar `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, pois o método [`getSelectedRow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow--) retorna -1 quando não há seleção, e -1 não faz parte do range de linhas de uma tabela.

Na sua classe `JFrameAltera`, após alterar para `JDialog`, o construtor passará a ficar assim:

```
public JFrameAltera(Frame parent, boolean isModal) {
    super(parent, isModal);
    initComponents();
}
```

O primeiro parâmetro representa de qual frame a tela foi originada, e o segundo torna a tela modal(ou seja, enquanto ela estiver aberta, a tela originária fica bloqueada para alteração).

No evento do botão salvar, você vai continuar salvando os dados novos no banco, e encerrar a tela, adicionando `this.dispose();`.

Baseado no código apresentado, você vai criar um método onde irá abstrair os dados salvos em um objeto e retorná-lo, utilizei a classe `Object` aqui apenas para demonstrar:

```
 public Object[] recuperaDados(){

    Object[] obj = {
     jf1.getText(),
     jf2.getText(),
     jf3.getText(),
     jf4.getText()
    };

     return obj;
 }
```

Agora na classe principal, no mesmo método onde você abre a janela de alteração, você vai alterar conforme abaixo:

```
private void jbAlterarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    if (jTable.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
        JFrameAltera tela2 = new JFrameAltera(this, true);
        tela2.preencheDados(jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString(),
                jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString(),
                jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString(),
                jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString());
        tela2.setVisible(true);

        Object[] obj = tela2.recuperaDados();
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length && i < jTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            jTable.setValueAt(obj[i], jTable.getSelectedRow(), i);
        }
    }
}
```

O método agora checa se há linha selecionada antes de abrir a tela(`getSelectedRow() != -1`), e assim que a tela é fechada, já recupera os dados e salva na tabela.

Com essas alterações, o método `readtable` perde seu sentido e pode ser removido.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente; Obrigado!

Comment: @LucasH.Rosa que bom que, mesmo a resposta estando um pouco generica, lhe ajudou. Você pode concluir a duvida aceitando a resposta, clicando no `v` a esquerda dela :)